# How to store the list object to Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I want to insert a list of items into a sqlflite TABLE but could not figure out how to do so. and how to get the data from the table.
I already initialized the database and created the table. Got the data from a PHP file linked with my database. but when want to save locally, I am facing the problem.

"Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer) sql 'INSERT INTO orders (name, partner_id) VALUES (?, ?)' args [RMA/04925, [10304, SMEG CARE]]}"

This is my model:

```
class Order {
String name;
List<dynamic> partnerId;
Order({this.name, this.partnerId});
Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
name = json['name'];
partnerId = json['partner_id'].cast<dynamic>();
}
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
data['name'] = this.name;
data['partner_id'] = this.partnerId;
return data;
}
}
```

This is my HTTP method toke the JSON data from the server :

```
static getOrders() async {
Response response;
Dio dio = Dio();
try {
final cookie = await LocalStorage.get(Config.COOKIE_KEY);
Map<String, dynamic> headers = {
'Cookie': cookie,
'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
};
Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {
'limit': 20,
};
response = await dio.get(Address.getOrders,
queryParameters: queryParameters, options: Options(headers: headers));
List responseJson = json.decode(response.data);
return responseJson.map((m) => Order.fromJson(m)).toList();
} catch (e) {
return print(e);
}
}
}
```

This is the place where I call the method to get the JSON and save to SQLite :

```
@override
void initState() {
UserDio.getOrders().then((val) {
dbHelper.truncateTable();
insert(val);
});
insert(List<Order> orders) {
orders.forEach((item) {
dbHelper.save(item);
});
}
```

And this is my Save method to save the JSON to the SQLite

```
Future<Order> save(Order order) async {
var dbClient = await db;
await dbClient.insert(TABLE, order.toJson());
return order;
}
```

This is my table structure

```
_onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
await db
.execute("CREATE TABLE $TABLE (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, partnerId TEXT)");
}
```